# Android Motionlayout: Android resource linking failed

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I keep getting build errors after a refactor to motionlayout 2.0.0-beta1 (I know it's not the newest version - beta2 produces same errors).

Here's the stacktrace:

```xml
AAPT: /Users/TBS/StudioProjects/ExampleApp/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:6514: error: resource attr/flow_horizontalSeparator (aka com.example:attr/flow_horizontalSeparator) not found.
/Users/TBS/StudioProjects/ExampleApp/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:6514: error: resource attr/flow_verticalSeparator (aka com.example:attr/flow_verticalSeparator) not found.
/Users/TBS/StudioProjects/ExampleApp/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:6515: error: resource attr/flow_horizontalSeparator (aka com.example:attr/flow_horizontalSeparator) not found.
/Users/TBS/StudioProjects/ExampleApp/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:6515: error: resource attr/flow_verticalSeparator (aka com.example:attr/flow_verticalSeparator) not found.
/Users/TBS/StudioProjects/ExampleApp/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:6517: error: resource attr/flow_horizontalSeparator (aka com.example:attr/flow_horizontalSeparator) not found.
/Users/TBS/StudioProjects/ExampleApp/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:6517: error: resource attr/flow_verticalSeparator (aka com.example:attr/flow_verticalSeparator) not found.
/Users/TBS/StudioProjects/ExampleApp/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:6517: error: resource attr/motionProgress (aka com.example:attr/motionProgress) not found.
/Users/TBS/StudioProjects/ExampleApp/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:6860: error: resource attr/motionProgress (aka com.example:attr/motionProgress) not found.
/Users/TBS/StudioProjects/ExampleApp/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:6861: error: resource attr/motionProgress (aka com.example:attr/motionProgress) not found.
/Users/TBS/StudioProjects/ExampleApp/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:6876: error: resource attr/motionProgress (aka com.example:attr/motionProgress) not found.
/Users/TBS/StudioProjects/ExampleApp/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:6877: error: resource attr/motionProgress (aka com.example:attr/motionProgress) not found.
/Users/TBS/StudioProjects/ExampleApp/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:6877: error: resource attr/waveDecay (aka com.example:attr/waveDecay) not found.
/Users/TBS/StudioProjects/ExampleApp/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:7288: error: resource attr/motionPathRotate (aka com.example:attr/motionPathRotate) not found.
/Users/TBS/StudioProjects/ExampleApp/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:7290: error: resource attr/motionProgress (aka com.example:attr/motionProgress) not found.
/Users/TBS/StudioProjects/ExampleApp/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:7549: error: resource attr/motionProgress (aka com.example:attr/motionProgress) not found.
/Users/TBS/StudioProjects/ExampleApp/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:8270: error: resource attr/duration (aka com.example:attr/duration) not found.
error: failed linking references.
```

There's no indication as to what file produces the error and to my knowledge I don't use any of these attributes anywhere in my project.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This problem is related to Android Studio 3.6 and ConstraintLayout versions earlier than 2.0.0-beta3 - I've reported the issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138601946).  This is fixed in ConstraintLayout 2.0.0-beta3.

Android Studio 3.5 doesn't produce this error.

To make it work in AS 3.6 beta, upgrade to ConstraintLayout 2.0.0-beta3 or later.

Comment: We have to downgrade?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky No, there's a workaround. See my edited answer.

Comment: You can now update to constraint layout beta3 which fixes the issue.

Comment: @Laimiux How to upgrade the ContraintLayout? I'm new to android and using studio canary 4. Does it mean that the Motion example on android github page is obsolete? https://github.com/android/animation-samples/tree/master/Motion

Comment: I've just learnt it. `File > Project Structure > Dependencies > All Modules > Add Dependency (Plus button) > Library Dependency > On Step 1, search "androidx.constraintlayout" > choose the latest version (at the moment it is 2.0.0-beta4) > OK > OK` Done. It has an information message, "Gradle promoted library version from 2.0.0-beta2 to 2.0.0-beta4". Now you can build it and run it.

Comment: implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4"
upgrading to this beta version of constraintlayout worked for me

Answer (score 4):

If even upgrading *ConstraintLayout* doesn't help, try to add **format** attribute to your *attr* declaration in your *attrs.xml* file.

```
<resources>
    <attr name="yourAttrName" format="string" />
</resources>
```

**Choose proper format for your attribute.**

Comment: After upgrading android studio 3.6 and gradle plugin to latest version faced this issue. Adding format solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

upgrading to constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4, worked for me ,
or later version. This happens after you upgrade android studio to 3.6

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded gradle version to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0` then faced this issues, just downgrade gradle version to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3` and problem resolved

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do two things:

1. Update your android studio.
2. add Latest dependency implementation

   `'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-rc1'`